# Java specify custom properties on Fields/Methods

Tags: java, reflections

I have a huge class with 500 members.
Each member will have properties whether it can be Filled/Edited based on business logic .

```
public class Person{
public String firstName; 
//500 more Fields below
}
```

And similarly other 500 fields .

Consumer of the class will need whether the firstName can be Filled/Edited .

Straight forward way is

```
Enum FieldProperty{
CanBeEdited,CanBeFilled
}
public class Person{
public String firstName; 
List<FieldProperty> firstNameProperties = list(CanBeFilled)
//500 more Fields below
}
```

How to efficiently represent this ?

Comment: Do these fill/edit properties vary between different instances of the class, or are they static?

Comment: Good question @Mauricio . They will vary for every instance .

Comment: that business logic that determines the state of these properties can be persisted, or is calculated only 'on the fly'?

Comment: It is computed on the fly based on the other members values. These properties are completely derivable based on the state . Hence i am looking for an efficient way . However the properties can change between fields .

Answer (score 0):

I am settling with below approach .

```
public class UiProperties<T>{
  Boolean CanBeEdited;
  Boolean CanBeFilled;
  Boolean CanBeDeleted;
}
public class Person{
public UiProperties<String> firstName; 
public UiProperties<String> lastName; 
public UiProperties<Date> dob; 
//500 more Fields below
}
```